# Authy.js with Angular 2 2.0.0 webpack with AngularClass WebPack Starter

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am using AngularClass https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter as the base of my project, I am using the Angular2 stable 2.0 version.

Now I want to use Authy.js to validate the phone number.

I installed npm authy -save to my application and not able to import the Authy to one of my component.

Please help.

Comment: Post some code and the error you are getting. We can't help you with zero data.